# How to get multiple dimensions in Bar chart - SAPUI5 VizFrame

Tags: charts, sapui5, bar-chart

I am new to SAPUI5, I am trying to get multiple dimensions in Bar chart using VizFrame. I need chart to be displayed like the below image:

[image]

Please check my [code](https://embed.plnkr.co/Z9rm6CFBTFdhddgjIRTi/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your work & time !! .. I have made it using setVizProperties > plotArea > dataPointStyle > rules .. This is the updated [link](https://embed.plnkr.co/Z9rm6CFBTFdhddgjIRTi/).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for Bar graph to show the **Amount vs Days**.

Here is the [working link.](https://plnkr.co/edit/bqqFhogA8Zvq31HRYkcE?p=preview)

I have updated **_setupChart** methods as below.

```
_setupChart: function() {
    var oVizFrame = this.getView().byId("idVizFrame");
    oVizFrame.setModel(new JSONModel('./data.json'));
    var oDataset = new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset({
        dimensions: [{
            name: "Days",
            value: "{Days}"
        }],
        measures: [{
            name: "Amount",
            value: "{Amount}"
        }],
        data: {
            path: "/dueDays"
        }
   });
   oVizFrame.setDataset(oDataset);
   oVizFrame.setVizType('bar');
   var feedValueAxis = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
       "uid": "valueAxis",
       "type": "Measure",
       "values": ["Amount"]
   });
   var feedCategoryAxis = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
       "uid": "categoryAxis",
       "type": "Dimension",
       "values": ["Days"]
   });
   oVizFrame.addFeed(feedValueAxis);
   oVizFrame.addFeed(feedCategoryAxis);
}
```

And also i have updated the data json as below

```
{
    "dueDays": [{  
        "Days": "Current",
        "Amount": "44334.00"
      }, {          
        "Days": "1 to 30",
        "Amount": "53454.00"
      }, {          
        "Days": "31 to 60",
        "Amount": "34443.65"
      }, {          
        "Days": "61 to 90",
        "Amount": "65554.43"
      }, {          
        "Days": "91 to 120",
        "Amount": "43524.00"
      },{           
        "Days": "121 to 150",
        "Amount": "54554.00"
      }, {          
        "Days": "151 to 180",
        "Amount": "43324.00"
      }, {          
        "Days": "Above 180",
        "Amount": "54355"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks !! But I need bars to be in different colors as the attached image.

Comment: In the same [working link](https://plnkr.co/edit/bqqFhogA8Zvq31HRYkcE?p=preview) I have updated the answer. But I don't think thats what you want     @Yal